# NUXTJS share JS method with Store Getters

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I want to write a simple JS method that I will use both in Store GETTERS.

I created a new file: `/plugins/myMethod.js` and added it to `nuxt.config.js` (at plugins part).

Follows the content of the file:

```
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  // Inject $hello(msg) in Vue, context and store.
  inject('exportaData', msg => console.log(`Data is: ${msg}!`))
}
```

I can use this method in Vue Components and in store ACTIONS, but not in Store GETTERS. I tried `this.$myMethod(1)` without any success.

Follows the code of `store/data.js`

```
export const getters = {
    hoje: state => {
      console.log('Running getter HOJE')
      this.$exportaData('12345')
    },
}
```

and in my Vue component:

```
<p>DATA: {{ $store.getters['datas/hoje'] }}</p>
```

Any idea how to access my custom method in the store getter?

Thanks

Comment: There is an example in the documentation with a similar use of inject in the store https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#inject-in-root--context


Сan you show the full text of the error when using myMethod in store?

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I updated my code and I noticed that it works fine in Store's ACTIONS but not in GETTERS.